# Unbalanced ram size and dual channel

Tags: memory, dual-channel

The more high-end laptop comes with soldered RAM + a ram slot which is populated.

The problem is that I'm looking at the new ROG Zephyrus 2021 and it comes in my region with max 16GB RAM, 8 soldered, and 8Gb on the stick, working in dual channel.

I'm doing a lot of CAD and 16GB is not enough for my need, however, it is not clear what would be the penalty of not being in a dual channel.

Some Intel CPUs have a feature called Flex Mode to accelerate unbalanced ram, however, this is an AMD Ryzen R9-5900HS processor.

There is a lot of unclear, confusing, and contradicting info on the web about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not dual channel is a benefit is highly dependant on the task. For games there is often a boost, but it is far from a doubling in performance as most tasks are CPU bound. It could mean 75% faster to load stuff from RAM to the graphics card, but typically the actual performance boost is likely 10-25%.

Hard disk speeds limit things far more by comparison and if you are hitting memory limits and having to page out memory to disk and back in then that will already penalise you far more than falling back to single channel RAM.

The only way to know if your system does some kind of "flex" dual channel mode is to try it by benchmarking your RAM before and after fitting the new RAM.

The only way to know if you can live with more RAM that is slightly slower is to try it.